# Cascading dropdown list using Ajax call

Tags: ajax, cascading, visual

I want a cascading dropdown list in a SharePoint visual web part.

How can i do this? Any way to use Ajax? Need an example with code.

Comment: Where is the data for the drop-down lists coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create an Application page with `WebMethods` defined and than use simple jQuery Ajax to call the methods..

Please have a look at
[Call WebMethod from JS in Visual web Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98184/call-webmethod-from-js-in-visual-web-part/98191#98191)

> ```
> $.ajax({
>      type: "POST",
>      url: siteUrl + "/_layouts/SolutionName/WebMethods.aspx/Recount",
>      data: "{'data':'" + data + "'}",
>      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>      dataType: "json",
>      async: true,
>      success: function (data) {
>          response(data["d"]);
>      },
>      error: function (result) {
>          //alert("Error");
>      }
>  });
> ```

OR

You can simply use [SPServices.Cascading Dropdown](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns)